# Caller id faker

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application to fake my mobile number to outgoing call. How to do this in android? I havent seen any api/control available to do this? Does android allow this? Is it legal for all the countries? Please give me some insight in this.

Comment: Rubbish question.  Please ask less pointless questions in future.  Hint: Sticking a question mark after a statement doesn't make it a question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can "edit" your outbound caller id, because your network provider is the one sending it to the recipient. What you probably can do is hide it.

Here is another SO question regarding this:

[android Outbound caller id - on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788205/android-outbound-caller-id-on-off)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but as far as I know the only thing stored on your SIM-card that identifies it is the IMEI number. Your phone number is probably stored in a database server somewhere, which would make it a lot harder to fake than just writing a little android app.

Answer (score 0):

the caller id is submitted by your provider, you can only tell your provider not to send the id (emergency calls will ever send the id), but there are some VoIp Providers whiche are able to fake the caller id.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to develop an android application to fake my mobile number to outgoing call. How to do this in android?

It is not possible.

> Does android allow this? Is it legal for all the countries?

No, Android doesn't allow this - probably because it is almost certainly illegal in every country that runs telecommunication systems that conform to international regulations.

Your phone provider is responsible for providing your 'caller id' (your phone number) to whoever you call. In most cases (depending on which country and which provider) you will have the option to 'hide' your telephone number but that isn't guaranteed everywhere in the world nor with all providers.

Even then, this is something that you have to do manually and cannot be done by software. The link to the SO question that cularis mentions has an answer by me which explains (or tries to explain) why it isn't even possible to hide your 'caller id' with software.