# Is there a way to access the 'hide my phone number' (caller ID) function with code in Android studio?

Tags: java, android

When you dial a phone number (on your Android phone), the person being called can see your phone number.
If you do not wish that, you can hide your phone number for outgoing calls from your phone by activating the corresponding feature.

Is there a way to access (toggle) this caller ID feature (hide/show) with code? I searched on the Internet but couldn't find anything.

And of course, if it is possible, what would be the code/method to do so?

Comment: Keywords here are `caller ID` and `setOutgoingCallerIdDisplay` and I found afterwards [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788205/android-outbound-caller-id-on-off) and [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510856/how-to-programatically-hide-caller-id-on-android) - but without definitive answer.

Comment: Apparently this is not a simple topic. I thought there is a direct method or function to toggle with code but it seems that it is not really the case. Surprising for such a feature.